# Haskell - arbitrary condition count

Tags: haskell, boolean-expression, higher-order-functions

I have a midterm exam about Haskell coming up and I'm trying to write a function that counts elements in a list based on whether each element matches a user-supplied boolean condition.

If the condition is hard coded, it's simple:

```
countEven :: [Int] -> Int
countEven [] = 0
countEven (h:t) = fromEnum (mod h 2==0)+countEven t

countOdds :: [Int] -> Int
countOdds [] = 0
countOdds (h:t) = fromEnum(mod h 2/=0)+countOdds t
```

Simple, right? Add the cast of the boolean expression applied to the head to the running total, and you'll have a count of how many elements in the list satisfy that condition.

However, suppose I want to write a higher-order function where I supply the boolean expression and every element in the list is tested against that expression.

This is what I have so far:

```
countCond :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int
countCond _ [] = 0
```

Now I'm unsure how I would write the recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we were writing this in an imperative language, it would look like (pseudo code)

```
int countBy(cond :: int -> bool, xs :: [int]) {
    int cnt = 0;
    foreach(x in xs) {
        if (cond(x)) {
            cnt += 1;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Clearly, we are going over every element in the list and adding `1` to `cnt` if it meets the condition.  If we wanted to, we could modify this somewhat to factor out the loop body (assuming this pseudo language has closures)

```
int countBy(cond :: int -> bool, xs :: [int]) {
    int cnt = 0;

    int body(int elem, int currentCnt) {
        if (cond(elem)) {
            return currentCnt + 1;
        } else {
            return currentCnt;
        }
    };

    foreach(x in xs) {
        cnt = body(x, cnt);
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

So we can see that our iteration is only dependent on our current value and the result obtained from the previous iteration.  This kind of pattern is called a *fold*, and they can be elegantly represented in Haskell using the built-in `fold*` functions.  Usually, `foldr` is a good choice, it's hard to go wrong with it.  The type of `foldr` is

```
foldr :: (x -> acc -> acc) -> acc -> [x] -> acc
```

I've purposely changed the type variables from what you'd see in GHCi to make it a bit more clear.  The `acc` type variable is for the *accumulator*.  It is the value that is updated on each iteration.  The `x` is the type of the elements of your list.  `foldr` takes as its first argument a function that acts as your loop body.  This function takes an element of the list and the accumulator and returns the next accumulator.  `foldr` then takes an initial accumulator value and finally a list to iterate over.  We can write `countBy` in Haskell as

```
countBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
countBy cond xs =
    foldr          -- Think of this as a for loop
        body       -- The body of our for loop
        0          -- The initial value for cnt
        xs         -- The list to iterate over
    where
        body elem currentCnt =
            if cond elem
                then currentCnt + 1
                else currentCnt
```

You could even in-line the `body` to write

```
countBy cond =
    foldr (
        \x cnt ->
            if cond x
                then cnt + 1
                else cnt
        )
        0
```

I also left off the `xs` parameter for a more point-free style.  Notice how this even looks almost like the original imperative style.  You can of course make this more compact, and I certainly would.  This can fit on one line without much trouble.

```
countBy cond = foldr (\x cnt -> if cond x then cnt + 1 else cnt) 0
```

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to write the recursion yourself, you only have to look at the definition of `foldr` to figure out how:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f b []     = b
foldr f b (x:xs) = foldr f (f x b) xs
```

Here `f` is our `body` and `b` is our accumulator.  So if we follow this style:

```
countBy' :: (a -> Bool) -> Int -> [a] -> Int
countBy' cond cnt [] = cnt
countBy' cond cnt (x:xs)
    | cond x    = countBy' cond (cnt+1) xs
    | otherwise = countBy' cond cnt xs

countBy xs = countBy' 0 xs
```

Or more simply

```
countBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countBy cond [] = 0
countBy cond (x:xs)
    | cond x    = countBy cond xs + 1
    | otherwise = countBy cond xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to decompose the problem into smaller pieces. For instance, you could start by filtering the list according to the user-supplied test function and then return its length. Makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the recursive call is exactly the same, you just need to replace the condition with a call to the user-supplied function:

```
countCond f (h:t) = fromEnum(f h) + countCond f t
```

Comment: In that case you should write `fromEnum (f h) + countCond f t`.

Answer (score 1):

since the function is going to give you the correct values, just filter:

```
countCond :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int
countCond f xs = length $ filter f xs
```

Thus, your previous function would look like:

```
countOdd xs = length $ filter odd xs
```

I think that is easier ...